# Using jQuery append with Grails remotefunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

Running into a problem with the way the remoteFunction works within Grails. I completely understand that it's an AJAX function, however I need it to be a synchronous call, and can't seem to get the asynchronous:false option to work.

Code:

```
 function getNewBlock(){
    var id = ${instance.id};
    var $element = $('#elements ul li.selectedAdd');
    $element.removeClass('selectedAdd');
    ${remoteFunction(
        action:'createBlock',
        update:'right-side',
        asynchronous:false,
        params:'\'id=\'+ escape(id)'
    )};
            //NEED TO APPEND THIS NEW BLOCK TO THE LIST OF BLOCKS ALREADY ON THE RIGHT
};
```

Which is fired from a button event when the user picks an item on the left side of the screen. It runs a service method and creates a new block, returning it to the screen. However, when the above function finishes, it rewrites the right-side div, dropping what was there before when we need it to append the new block.

How would I go about doing this when the remoteFunction is asynchronous?

Thanks!

Comment: You would be better off just writing the jQuery code you need rather than trying to make remoteFunction work for your requirements.

Comment: Good point. Once I broke it out of the remoteFunction and into a straight AJAX function, I got it working.

Comment: I would be interested to hear the reason why it has to be synchronous.

Comment: Well it doesn't need to be sycnchronous now. Grails remoteFunction on success does `success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#right-side').html(data);}` When I needed it to do `success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#right-side').append(data);}` All my elements on the right were getting completely replaced when the call would come back.